# Не работает отправка формы, ReCaptcha. Ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

Уже который день бьюсь с обработкой ReCaptcha. Может кто мог бы указать на ошибку или подсказать как должно быть, серверную часть делаю впервые на PHP, поэтому строгу не судите. До этого отправку данных из формы на эмейл выполнял другой код, решил переписать с обработкой капчи и теперь вообще не отсылаются данные.

Код PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = trim($_POST["Name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["E-mail");
    $phone = trim($_POST["Phone"]);

    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

    }


    if(empty($name) OR empty($phone) OR empty($email) OR empty ($captcha)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        exit;
    }
    $recipient = "vladknure@gmail.com";
$subject = "Biotech.org.ua. Пользователь.";

$email_content = "Name: $name\n";
$email_content = "Phone: $phone\n\n";
$email_content = "E-mail: $email\n\n";

$email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LdxczcUAAAAAMeDD8JwV8JkjAGKDhghdyjGK2vK&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);
if($decoded_response['success'] == true) {
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        echo " congrats";
    } else {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "couldnt be sent";
    }

} else {
    http_response_code(400);
    echo "you are spammer";
}

}

?>
```

Код формы:

```
<form action="/" class="form" method="post">

                    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
                    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Biotech">
                    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="sales@biotech.org.ua">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Контактные данные пользователя">
                    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input id="email" type="text" name="E-mail" pattern="^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон">
                    </div>
                    <div id="formresult"></div>





                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-button" value="Отправить">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdxczcUAAAAAKsbbef_VQgblw-khfd-S0RCL0Vq" style=""></div>


                </form>
```

AJAX-запрос:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var th = $(this);
        var contactForm = $('.form');
        var formresult = $('#formresult');
        var formData = $(contactForm).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "mailer.php",
            data: formData,
            success: function(response) {

                alert("Благодарим за проявленный интерес к нашей продукции.");
                $('.cityAddress').removeClass('active');
                $('.form-block').removeClass('active');
                setTimeout( function() {
                    th.trigger('reset');
                }, 1000)

            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("error");
                $('.cityAddress').removeClass('active');
                $('.form-block').removeClass('active');
                setTimeout( function() {
                    th.trigger('reset');
                }, 1000)

            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Если Вы работаете на локальном хосте, то гугл не может Вам выслать ответ на локальный хост. Посылать ответ как бы некуда

Comment: нет, заливаю на хостинг

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работающий пример, все проверил. Перепроверьте свои ключи, тестировал на своих для локалки.

Ваши ошибки:

- неправильно закрываете скобки
- $(contactForm) делаете для $('.form'), зачем два раза $($('.form'))?
- не обязательно делать кнопку type="submit"
- в приведенном примере не подключен скрипт recaptcha/api.js, jquery.js
- неясно когда выполняется ваш js до загрузки страницы или после (для этого надо выполнять его в `$(function () { _тут_ });`)
- остальное не помню

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#submit-button').on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var contactForm = $('.form');
                var formData = contactForm.serialize();

                console.log(formData);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "recap.php",
                    data: formData
                })
                    .done(function () {
                        console.log("success");
                        $('#output').html(data.responseText);
                    })
                    .fail(function (data) {
                        console.log("error");
                        $('#output').html(data.responseText);

                    })
                    .always(function () {
                        console.log("complete");
                    });
                ;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="form" method="post">

    <!-- Hidden Required Fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="project_name" value="Biotech">
    <input type="hidden" name="admin_email" value="sales@biotech.org.ua">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_subject" value="Контактные данные пользователя">
    <!-- END Hidden Required Fields -->

    <div class="input-group">

        <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Имя и фамилия" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">

        <input id="email" type="text" name="E-mail"
               pattern="^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$" placeholder="E-mail"
               required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">

        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон">
    </div>
    <div id="formresult"></div>


    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdxczcUAAAAAKsbbef_VQgblw-khfd-S0RCL0Vq" style=""></div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit-button" value="Отправить">


</form>

<div id="output"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: user
 * Date: 11.11.2017
 * Time: 14:32
 */

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    var_dump($_REQUEST);

    $name = trim($_POST["Name"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["E-mail"]);
    $phone = trim($_POST["Phone"]);

    $captcha = '';

    if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }


    if (empty($name) OR empty($phone) OR empty($email) OR empty ($captcha)) {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "имя/телефон/почта/капча не введены";
        exit;
    }
    $recipient = "vladknure@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Biotech.org.ua. Пользователь.";

    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content = "Phone: $phone\n\n";
    $email_content = "E-mail: $email\n\n";

    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LdxczcUAAAAAMeDD8JwV8JkjAGKDhghdyjGK2vK&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $decoded_response = json_decode($response, true);
    if ($decoded_response['success'] == true) {
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            http_response_code(200);
            echo " congrats";
        } else {
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "couldnt be sent";
        }

    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "you are spammer";
    }

}
```

Comment: работает, но при непроверенной капче все равно "success". у меня была такая же ситуация, вот это было моей главное проблемой - не получалось аяксом результат с сервера корректно обработать

Comment: потому что "success" вызывается в done(). т.е в любом случае будет показываться success. вот как фильтровать успешную отправку и нет?

Comment: @VladTeryoshin ну так посмотрите какой http код аякс ассоциирует  с fail() и с пхп отправляйте этот код с помощью http_response_code()

Comment: @VladTeryoshin все работает, отправляется 400 и срабатывает fail()

Comment: почему-то постоянно получаю код 200. независимо от исхода. я уже смотрел настройки хостинга, там все ОК.

Comment: fail() не отрабатывает вообще
я ни  в коем случае не гвоорю, что вы неправы, просто не понимаю в чем может быть причина. код с условием (пустые поля) отрабатывает, но по итогу возвращается 200....а не 400

Comment: @VladTeryoshin у вас отладчик есть? если нет, установите и разберите свой скрипт по шагам, тогда станет все понятно.

Comment: есть, он заходит в код на проверку пустых полей, где должен вернуть код 400, но все равно возвращает по итогу код 200
так а как так выходит, что у Вас все работает, а у меня нет? может я что-то не так делаю в другом?

Comment: действительно, в PhpStorm все работает, а на хостинге нет..что за чушь